# How do I make two constraints match each other in iOS Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a view that is sized to the width of the screen with a 1x1 ratio of width to height (matching height). I have a view below that square view that is a set height from the bottom. What I want is for the top view to be centered in the blank space. So I would love to just set 1 constraint for the top and 1 constraint for the bottom to say, match. Then if there are x number of points of available, each constraint should be size x / 2.

So far, I haven't been able to find a constraint setting that can do this. Could someone describe how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you add 2 transparent views, 1 above and 1 below, pin the edges to your existing views and set the 2 new views to have equal height.

Comment: I'll play with this idea. Thanks!

Comment: I took that idea and did something a little different. I created a view that matched the space I wanted to center inside. Then I told my square view to center itself in that new view. I guess there just is not a way to do it using only constraints. Thanks.

Comment: @Gandalf458 I'd actually say your way is the better way to do it, rather than just having transparent views thrown into the UI for the sake of constraints...